# Come in birch meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a book I'm reading there is a question as following

> Does it come in birch

Here is the situation:

> But wait, there’s more! There are other particles besides these four and they all fall into columns as well. Each column looks exactly like the first column (with the same properties like charge and force interaction) except the particles in them have more mass.24 We call each of these columns a “generation,” and we’ve discovered three of these generations.
>   You might immediately have some questions about our table of particles:
>   Does it come in birch?

My question is what does that sentence mean? I have searched "come in birch" in dictionaries and google but there is no information about it.

Please explain to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant definition for "come" in this context is:

> *[no object, with adverbial]* Be sold, available, or found in a specified form.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come)</sub>

It's a joke. "Table" can refer to something formatted in rows and columns (as it does in the rest of the paragraph) or it can refer to [a piece of furniture](https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb1/birch-kitchen-dining-tables-c46129-a136341~457016.html), as it does in "Does it come in birch?".

You might say that they're *turning the tables*.